# Use HTTP_REFERER within a twig template

Tags: 9

I have a FAQ page with five nested bootstrap 5 accordions and I need to have one accordion item or another open depending on the page the user is coming from.

I tried using this:

```
{% set previousURL = app.request.headers.get('referer') %}
```

but I get nothing.

Using Drupal 9.

Comment: `app` is something the Symfony Twig Bundle adds to Twig templates which does not exist in Drupal. Did you discover this in a Symfony Framework tutorial?

Comment: I would solve this using javascript instead of twig.

Answer (score -1):

To do this you must either:

- [Create a Twig extension for Drupal](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-9-creating-custom-twig-functions-and-filters) in a custom module. The extension type you should create is the `function` type.
- [Implement hook_preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/9.4.x). See also, [this short tutorial](https://www.purencool.digital/development/adding-global-variable-twig-layer-every-part-page-drupal-8).